[tag][error] TypeError: (0 , os_1.availableParallelism) is not a function
I am getting these errors when I tried to build the Angular project
angular-errorw.log
[error] TypeError: (0 , os_1.availableParallelism) is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\anike\OneDrive\ecommerce-project\03-frontend\angular-ecommerce\node_modules\piscina\dist\src\index.js:37:54)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\anike\OneDrive\ecommerce-project\03-frontend\angular-ecommerce\node_modules\piscina\dist\src\main.js:5:33)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)

package.json
{
  "name": "angular-ecommerce",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^14.0.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^6.5.2",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^14.2.13",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^14.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "typescript": "~4.7.2"
  }
}

I was also getting this error message on my VS Ccode
Command failed: npm i --package-lock-only --prefix C:\Users\anike\AppData\Local\Temp\exhort_gaocBM
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: angular-ecommerce@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/compiler-cli@14.3.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli
npm ERR! dev @angular/compiler-cli@"^14.0.0" from the root project npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/compiler-cli@"^18.0.0" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@18.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR! dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^18.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\anike\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run ...

I am learning Angular, so I am here for some help.

I have seen your project have package:
....
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^18.0.0",
...

it not compatible with other angular package. It using version 18, but your angular using version 14.
you should change your version of package compatible of angular. Try to set your package to version 14
....
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.0.0",
...

and the error:
...
[error] TypeError: (0 , os_1.availableParallelism) is not a function
...

It may be a error of nodejs version not compatible with package read this Angular version compatibility and pick a match nodejs version for your angular project.
Hope it help!

Hi, thanks man, It actually get resolved once I updated Angular 14 to 18, reinstalled the Angular CLI and updated the typescript version to 5.4.5

os.availableParallelism() was added in Node 18.14/19.4. So, the error comes from incompatible nodejs and angular versions.

I'm getting the same error, trying to build an Angular project in VS Code on Mac. Also curious for an answer.

It get resolved once I updated Angular 14 to 18, reinstalled the Angular CLI (but first you have to delete node_module directory and package-lock.json file) and updated the typescript version to 5.4.5. and also dont forget to update your angular.json file( just change the versions of typescript and angular to the one you just installed)
